# How to populate the dropdown list from sql server database using LinkedHashMap in java

Tags: java, sql-server, jstl, html.dropdownlistfor, linkedhashmap

In SQL Server database I have a table which has three columns namely Ref_Name,Ref_from and Ref_to.Now I want a dropdown list  to hold values row-wise i.e all column values of the row should be in the dropdown list in following way:-

> **Reference-1(2014-10-10 07:17:00.000 to 2014-10-10 08:46:00.000)**
>
> **Reference-2(2014-09-01 10:00:00.000 to 2014-09-01 11:00:00.000)**

For this I have used LinkedHashMap as:-

```
    public LinkedHashMap<String, List<String>> connect()
    {
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        try
        { 
            con = getConnection();
            stmt = con.createStatement();
            String sql="select Ref_No,From_Date,To_Date from Ref_time";
            stmt.executeQuery(sql);
            rs = stmt.getResultSet();
            while (rs.next()) 
            {
                list.add(rs.getString(2));
                list.add(rs.getString(3));
                ref.put(rs.getString(1), list);
            }

        }
        catch( Exception e )
        {
            System.out.println("\nException "+e);
        }
        finally
        {
            //closeConnection(stmt, rs, con);
        }
         return ref;
    }
```

When I use it in jsp as

```
<select name="ref_logtime">
<c:forEach var="aff" items="${obj.connect()}">
<option value="${aff.key}">${aff.key}</option>
<option value="${aff.value}">${aff.value}</option>
</c:forEach>
</select>
```

Then in dropdown ,I get values as:-

```
 Reference-1
 All datetime entries are shown here
 Reference-2
 All datetime entries are shown here
```

But I want my dropdown list to have values row wise.How to do that?

Comment: change `ArrayList<String> List` to `ArrayList<String> list` it is more readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with your code. First, every *reference* mapping needs to have its own `List`. Currently, the list is being shared and hence both the reference entries would show all the dates. Change the code as

```
rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
while (rs.next()) 
{
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add(rs.getString(2));
    list.add(rs.getString(3));
    ref.put(rs.getString(1), list);
}
```

The second problem is with the JSTL tag. You need only one `<option>` tag within the loop which would run twice for you (because you have two *reference* entries coming from the database) to generate the two `<option>` tag entries.

```
<select name="ref_logtime">
  <c:forEach var="aff" items="${obj.connect()}">
    <option value="${aff.key}">${aff.key} ${aff.value}</option>
  </c:forEach>
</select>
```